# cakephp autocomplete - pass a parameter

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I currently have this code. I am trying to do an autocomplete based on a value in the dropdown. Problem is Im not sure how I can pass the selected value in the dropdown in the ajax request...

Using plain vanilla scriptaculous and prototype

```
  <form>
          <?php echo $this->Form->input('searchby', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $searchByList, 'label' => 'Search By:'));?>
                </b>
                    <?php echo $ajax->autoComplete('searchvalue', '/Controller/autoComplete/', array('minChars' => 2)); ?>
                <input name="search" type="submit" value="Search"/>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a search page, I recommend passing the parameters using GET instead of POST. Often times users bookmark their searches, if its done using a POST, then the results cannot be preserved.

Here is a (quickly hacked together) example of how to do an auto-complete.

Your search view

```
<form method="get" action="/controller/search">
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Search.searchby', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $searchByList, 'label' => 'Search By:'));?>
    <?php echo $ajax->autoComplete('Search.searchvalue', '/controller/autoComplete/', array('minChars' => 2)); ?>
    <input name="search" type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

It needs a controller named 'controller' that uses two functions ('search' and 'autocomplete')

```
function search() {

    // GET parameters for search
    $searchby  = (isset($this->params['url']['searchby'])) ? ( $this->params['url']['searchby']) : '';
    $searchvalue  = (isset($this->params['url']['searchvalue'])) ? ( $this->params['url']['searchvalue']) : '';


    // DO SEARCH HERE
    $conditions = array('searchby'=>$searchby, 'searchvalue' => $searchvalue);
    …etc…

}



function autocomplete() {
    if(!empty($this->data['Search']['searchvalue'])){
        $rs = $this->Search->findAll(array('searchvalue' => "LIKE {$this->data['Search']['searchvalue']}%" ));
        $this->set('searchvalues', $rs);
    } 
    $this->render('autocomplete', 'ajax');      
}
```

The autocomplete ajax piece needs a view template named 'autocomplete.ctp'

```
<!-- autocomplete.ctp -->
<ul>
<?php if(isset($searchvalues) && !empty($searchvalues)){ ?>
    <?php foreach($searchvalues as $t) { ?>
    <li><?php echo $t['Search']['searchvalue']; ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

This should get you pointed in the right direction.

(If what you wanted was to get the select tag value and pass it via ajax, then you should take a look at the ajax functions for serializing the form. You may have to hand code the javascript, as I don't know if the ajax helper has options for serializing the form. here's some code I've used to serialize *just* a select tag. may be helpful)

```
<?php
    $graph_type = array( 
        'impressions'=>'Impressions', 
        'click_throughs'=>'Click Throughs',
        'click_through_ratio'=>'Click Through Ratio',
        'time_with_brand'=>'Time with Brand', 
        'average_time_with_brand'=>'Average Time with Brand'
    );

    echo $html->selectTag('Graph/type', $graph_type, null, array('onChange' => 'event.returnValue = false; return false;', 'style' => 'margin-right:20px;'),null, false);
    echo $javascript->event("'GraphType'", "change", 
        $ajax->remoteFunction(
            array(
                'update' => 'graph_container',
                'url' => '/reports/ajax_graph_multiple',
                'with'=>"Form.serialize('reports_form')"
            )
        )
    );
?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but my question relates to how I can pass in searchBy in autocomplete() function autocomplete() {
    if(!empty($this->data['Search']['searchvalue'])){
        $rs = $this->Search->findAll(array('searchvalue' => "LIKE {$this->data['Search']['searchvalue']}%" ));
        $this->set('searchvalues', $rs);
    } 
    $this->render('autocomplete', 'ajax');      
}

Answer (score 0):

I see. You want the 'searchBy' parameter to be serialized so that it is available in your autocomplete function. [If you check out the documentation, there is an option for adding additional parameters.](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/ajax-autocompleter/)

There is a prototype function for serializing forms. I use it for my regular forms, but I've never used for autocomplete. Give this a try.

```
<form id='autocomplete_form' name='autocomplete_form'>
  <?php echo $this->Form->input('searchby', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $searchByList, 'label' => 'Search By:'));?>
  <?php echo $ajax->autoComplete('searchvalue', '/Controller/autoComplete/', array('minChars' => 2, 'parameters'=>"Form.serialize('autocomplete_form')")); ?>
  <input name="search" type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```